# recv in asyncio in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In the following code:

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
server_socket.bind(server_address)
server_socket.listen()

try:
    connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print(f'I got a connection from {client_address}!')

    buffer = b''

    while buffer[-2:] != b'\r\n':
        data = connection.recv(2)
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            print(f'I got data: {data}!')
            buffer = buffer + data

    print(f"All the data is: {buffer}")
finally:
    server_socket.close()
```

I would expect would be the following

```
I got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 49721)!
I got data: b'te'!
I got data: b'st'!
I got data: b'in'!
I got data: b'g1'!
I got data: b'\r\n'!
All the data is: b'testing1\r\n'
```

but, what i get is

```
I got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 49721)!
I got data: b't'!
I got data: b'e'!
I got data: b's'!
I got data: b't'!
I got data: b'i'!
I got data: b'n'!
I got data: b'g'!
I got data: b'1'!
I got data: b'\r\n'!
All the data is: b'testing1\r\n'
```

The recv method receives up to 2 bytes of data from the client socket and returns the data as a bytes object. If that's what it does, why doesn't it work, or is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.recv(2)` receives **up to** 2 bytes. It does not wait for 2.

If you've sent the data byte by byte, it will return it as so.

A typical loop retries `recv()` until you have all the data or the `recv()` is empty, signalling a closed connection.

Comment: And how can I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: @toxfu Create another loop with a 2 bytes buffer, calling recv until it is full.